# Creating Collections in Kinvey (Android)

Tags: android, kinvey

I recently started using Kinvey as a backend for my Android app. The documentation doesn't have a lot of info about Collections. I want to know if it's possible to create Collections using the same concepts applied to MySQL tables for example:

A Collection called Users will hold a User ID, Username, User Email

And another Collection called Items corresponding to users -> Item ID, Item Name, User ID.

Has anyone successfully created Collections like this using Kinvey?

kinvey.com

I have also contacted their support team about this bu no reply yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Kinvey and can help you at this.  Kinvey uses a NoSQL store on the back end, so the concepts are a little different than those of a relational database system like MySql, but in general the same thought process can apply.  A Collection is similar to a table, although it is Schema-less.  This means that attributes (columns in MySql terms) can be added dynamically as needed.  You simply create the collection, and then start saving data objects to it.  For more info on our Android library specifically, take a look at our [Data Store User Guide](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/datastore).

Comment: thanks does Kinvey support joins in Android for example if I wanted to query two collections, i haven't seen any examples relating to this in the guide.

Comment: Not currently, but a new version of the library is being released late this week that does support relationships.